# How to have DLL specific config file?

Tags: c#, dll, config

I wish to have multiple config files in my solution. For example, For my console application (Program.Main) I want to refer app.config file for any settings. While my console application internally calls a method of a class libray Dll1. Inside Dll1 I want the code to take some settings from Dll1.config. Similarly my Console application also calls a method of Dll2. Inside Dll2 I want the code to take settings from Dll2.config file.

Please help on how to achieve this. Also, is it possible or not?
I would be really helpful if you could provide with a small code sample.

Comment: Why not just put the necessary settings for Dll1 and Dll2 in the console application's config file?  Both DLLs will be able to access the Console's config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. Just like you can have exe.config file, its perfectly normal to have a dll.config file. Store DLL specific information in its config file. Later on you can access this configuration information from DLL by following code

```
var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string dllConfigData = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["dllConfigData"].Value;
```

Comment: I've never encountered a situation where I've needed to store settings in an config file for a DLL.  Why do you say it's "perfectly normal"?  I would consider it the exception, not the rule - and only in a very specific edge case (and I can't think of either).